# Character encoding in web applicaion running on Websphere Application Server 8.5

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, websphere

I have a problem with Cyrillic symbols represention (they looks as '0B0;lO') in IBM WebSphere Application I created.

So I use WebSphere 8.5 (Unix Red Hat) and application is a java-servlet which listens to HTTP POST Requests.

JVM properties on WebSphere are:

- Default Charset=UTF-8
- Default Charset= in use=UTF-8
- file.encoding=UTF-8

I have checked file encoding.properties and set encoding to UTF8. Requests to my application I send in UTF8 by following code:

```
   HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
   connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
   connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
   connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
   connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(resultXML.getBytes().length));
   connection.setUseCaches (false);
   connection.setDoInput(true);
   connection.setDoOutput(true);

   //Send request
   DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
             connection.getOutputStream ());
  // BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(wr, "UTF-8"));
   BufferedWriter br1 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(wr, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
   br1.write(resultXML);
   br1.close();
   wr.flush ();
   wr.close ();

   //Get Response
   BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
   String line;
   while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
   }
   rd.close();
```

In application HTTP Request Handler first of all I set encoding by:

```
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

But all Cyrillic symbols in request and response looks uncorrectly and when appplication put them to Oracle DB or simply to response these symbols have wrong view.

Help with problem, please!

Comment: How do you read your xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved.

Request Cyrillic symbols was processed correctly, problem was with response. Following code helped.

```
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream(), "UTF8"), true);
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++)
        {
            out.print(result.charAt(i));
        }

        out.flush();
```